# vitess implementation

Tags: vitess

Can someone please help me on how to implement a proper vitess cluster on production. I am going through the vitess DOC but I am unable to figure out how a proper cluster is setup with multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

We now have a user guide for running vitess in production: https://vitess.io/docs/user-guides/configuration-basic/